# sql request to retrieve each day max, min first and last record

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the min, and max, the first and the last record in my database mysql.
I'm looking for a high-performance query that takes no more than 15 minutes.

I have tested :

```
SELECT
  MIN(low),
  MAX(high),
  CONCAT(YEAR(date), "-", WEEK(date)) AS myweek,
  (select open from prices m where WEEK(m.date)=WEEK(prices.date) order by date LIMIT 1) as first_open,
  (select close from prices m where WEEK(m.date)=WEEK(prices.date) order by date desc LIMIT 1) as last_close
FROM prices
GROUP BY myweek
ORDER BY date;
```

But i have a error :

```
Erreur dans la requête (1055): Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'siteinfo.prices.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I can not correct this error because I do not have access to conf files and I do not have user superadmin.

I have tested too :

```
select 
DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y" "%m" "%d") as datetime, 
(select open from prices m where m.date like CONCAT(YEAR(datetime), "-[0]", Month(datetime), "-[0]", DAY(datetime), "%") and fk_cryptoid = 'f2a0ba90-93df-11e8-af1b-5968de90d63b'  order by date ASC LIMIT 1) as open,
(select close from prices m where m.date like CONCAT(YEAR(datetime), "-[0]", Month(datetime), "-[0]", DAY(datetime), "%") and fk_cryptoid = 'f2a0ba90-93df-11e8-af1b-5968de90d63b'  order by date DESC LIMIT 1) as close,
min(low) as low, 
max(high) as high 
from prices
where fk_cryptoid = 'f2a0ba90-93df-11e8-af1b-5968de90d63b' 
 GROUP BY datetime;
```

but CONCAT() does not return the day and the month with a zero in addition: 2018-1-2 and not 2018-01-02. Then this request takes too much time.

Model for table Prices :

```
id  int(11) Incrément automatique    
close   double NULL  
open    double NULL  
low double NULL  
high    double NULL  
date    datetime NULL    
createdAt   datetime     
updatedAt   datetime     
fk_cryptoid char(36) NULL
```

Comment: "I can not correct this error because I do not have access to conf files and I do not have user superadmin." Yes you can, just include `date` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: i can't group by date, i need take each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works for you, then I would suggest the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
SELECT MIN(low), MAX(high),
       CONCAT(YEAR(date), '-', WEEK(date)) AS myweek,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(open ORDER BY date), ',', 1) as first_open,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(close ORDER BY date DESC), ',', 1) as last_close
FROM prices
GROUP BY myweek
ORDER BY date;
```

Notes:

- This `first_open` and `last_close` columns will be strings.
- The assumption is that `open` and `close` do not have commas.  If they do, use a different separator.
- `GROUP_CONCAT()` has a default internal limit of about 1,000 bytes.  You can adjust that using server parameters.